# How to get disk free space from sftp? PHP

Tags: php, laravel

Is there any way possible to get the free space of your sever's directory on 'php'?.

Like on laravel:

```
Storage::disk('sftp')->getAvailableStorage();
```

Comment: The free space generally isn't allocated per directory.  You should provide more context such as the type of server you are on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. I used this library.
https://github.com/phanan/remote

```
 $config = json_decode($storage->config);
        $connection = new Remote([
            'host' => $config->host,
            'port' => 22,
            'username' => $config->username,
            'password' => $config->password,
        ]);

        $available_size = $connection->exec("df --block-size=1 /home | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}'");
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.disk-free-space.php

You can use the`disk_free_space` function  that returned free space in bytes

Comment: I'm pretty sure I said sftp.

Comment: @HnnE sorry. Don't saw it. If you have php on yours remote server, I think you can execute the command in shell. You can execute `df` command or php-file where you can use this function. I'm sure this Laravel function do same things.